# Symbolic Math Library in C/C++/Obj-C

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, symbolic-math, computer-algebra-systems

I am trying to implement a graphing calculator on the iPhone. I am looking for a library that can take strings of expressions or functions and let me manipulate them (find derivatives, intercepts, zeros, etc). Does anything like this exist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symbolic math lib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160911/symbolic-math-lib)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [GiNaC](http://www.ginac.de/About.html) for C++. GPL-licensed and actively maintained, last update only a month ago. I found old links to many others that don't seem to exist anymore; perhaps people simply found it easier to use GiNaC?