# Can't solve the mathematical expression using DDMathParser

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ddmathparser

I am using `DDMathParser` to parse the string expressions. I am working on one expression which is "`(2+x)6+2x+2y=5y+2x`", I am trying to parse it and evaluate it using `DDMathParser`. It can be considered as first degree function that I need to solve using Objective C.

Guys any ideas?

Help would be highly appreciated.

```
DDExpression * e = [DDExpression expressionFromString:expression error:error];
NSNumber *num = [e evaluateWithSubstitutions:substitutions evaluator:nil error:error];
```

Comment: What error or problem are you getting?

Comment: Not facing any error but getting 0 as "num" that should not be the result.

Comment: @Dave Delong can you please help on this?

Comment: see my answer below. It may not be what you want to hear but I think it is correct... I don't think that library does symbolic math.

Comment: Correct. DDMathParser is for evaluating expressions; it does not solve for unknown values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about `DDMathParser` (OK, I don't know anything about it), but [taking a look at the documentation](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki) gives some clues about what is going wrong with your code.

Based on the documentation, I could find not example of where `DDMathParser` could handle *symbolic* expressions. All of the examples on the Usage page show numeric expressions.

For symbolic math, see [Symbolic Math Library in C/C++/Obj-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210417/symbolic-math-library-in-c-c-obj-c) .

In addition, it looks like **you are trying to solve for two variables with a single equation**, which is certainly not going to result in a numeric solution.

However, if you are just trying to substitute values in for `x` and `y`, you should use the `$` sign before them as the [documentation](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Variables) says:

> If you don't know what the value of a particular term should be when
>   the string is constructed, that's ok; simply use a variable:
>
> ```
>      NSString *math = @"6 * $a";
> ```

So if you just want to substitute values in your expression, try using:

```
string expression = @"(2+$x)6+2*$x+2*$y";
```

Then fill in with values.

```
NSDictionary *s = @{@"x" : 42, @"y" : 43};
```

And evaluate.

```
DDMathEvaluator *eval = [DDMathEvaluator sharedMathEvaluator];
NSLog(@"%@", [eval evaluateString:expression withSubstitutions:s]);
```